# How to inflate an Intent in a fragment using achartengine

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, achartengine

The code below works, but the whole main view is replaced for the chart when I invoke itself.

I guess that the problem is located in how I start the chart Activity in startActivity(chart); in my framgment. If remove it, the fragment works well without replacement.

How could I send it to the main view???

```
public class Graph extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){


    // LineGraph - class which draws the graph using achartengine
    final LineGraph lineGraph = new LineGraph();
    final Intent chart = lineGraph.getIntent(inflater.getContext());

    startActivity(chart);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.graph1, container, false);  

}

}
```

Here the Activity:

```
    public class MainCharts extends Activity {
    Button btn1;

    @TargetApi(11)
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dash_app);

        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        StartFragment myFragment = new StartFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.myFragment, myFragment);
        ft.commit();

        btn1.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);

    }

    Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            Fragment newFragment;

            newFragment = new Graph();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/siddhuwarrier/ElasticDroid-Tablet/blob/develop/src/org/elasticdroid/fragments/ChartFragment.java) for an example on how to add an AChartEngine chart inside a fragment.